# AWS RDS (mysql) instance not connecting to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datagrip

I am trying to connect the AWS RDS Instance on a local machine using Datagrip. The RDS instance have public access and inbound traffic is allowed from my IP address + all traffic is allowed for testing, but keep getting connection error. Screenshots are attached below, not sure what's causing this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you connect any other way? For example using `mysql` CLI to check if connection works at all?

Comment: You have a whole bunch of subnets there, are all of them public or did the instance get created in a private subnet by chance?

Comment: I would also check mysql connector version as well. What version ar eyou using?

Comment: Also, take a look to AWS troubleshooting [guide 1](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/) and [guide 2](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-mysql-db/)